# Jackson - java.lang.EnumConstantNotPresentException when deserialization with JsonTypeInfo.DEDUCTION

Tags: java, spring, jboss, jackson, wildfly

I have *SpringBoot app (1.4.3.RELEASE)*. Recently I have upgraded Jackson (`com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype, com.fasterxml.jackson.core`) from `2.8.5` to `2.12.2` because of [polymorphic subtype deduction feature](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.12/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonTypeInfo.Id.html#DEDUCTION). Everything works just fine on my local development environment during unit tests and also when I'm running app from IDE.

The problem occurs when I push my changes to build and deploy it on development environment, where app is deployed on *Wildfly 21.0.2*. (as a WAR archive). Calling [ObjectMapper#readValue](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.12.2/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#readValue-java.io.InputStream-com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference-) throws `java.lang.EnumConstantNotPresentException` (detailed stack below).

There are no enums used in objects which I'm deserializing and I have already checked through Wildfly management console, that there is correct version of Jackson on deployed app. Now I am a bit clueless. Any ideas?

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo$Id.DEDUCTION
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.JacksonAnnotationIntrospector._findTypeResolver(JacksonAnnotationIntrospector.java:1424)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.JacksonAnnotationIntrospector.findTypeResolver(JacksonAnnotationIntrospector.java:522)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotationIntrospectorPair.findTypeResolver(AnnotationIntrospectorPair.java:225)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BasicDeserializerFactory.findTypeDeserializer(BasicDeserializerFactory.java:1584)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BasicDeserializerFactory.findPropertyTypeDeserializer(BasicDeserializerFactory.java:1748)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BasicDeserializerFactory.resolveMemberAndTypeAnnotations(BasicDeserializerFactory.java:2116)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BasicDeserializerFactory.constructCreatorProperty(BasicDeserializerFactory.java:1000)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BasicDeserializerFactory._addExplicitPropertyCreator(BasicDeserializerFactory.java:634)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BasicDeserializerFactory._addDeserializerConstructors(BasicDeserializerFactory.java:407)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BasicDeserializerFactory._constructDefaultValueInstantiator(BasicDeserializerFactory.java:283)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BasicDeserializerFactory.findValueInstantiator(BasicDeserializerFactory.java:224)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerFactory.buildBeanDeserializer(BeanDeserializerFactory.java:220)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerFactory.createBeanDeserializer(BeanDeserializerFactory.java:143)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createDeserializer2(DeserializerCache.java:414)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:349)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCache2(DeserializerCache.java:264)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCacheValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:244)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache.findValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:142)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.findRootValueDeserializer(DeserializationContext.java:479)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._findRootDeserializer(ObjectMapper.java:4405)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4214)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3214)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3197)
```

Comment: Would you kindly provide the class that you are trying to desrilize into it?  (`ObjectMapper.readValue()`)

Comment: Post your code as well

Answer (score 1):

Well, the problem was solved by explicit exclusion of Jackson related libraries in jboss-deployment-structure.xml file (as shown on code below). Without these exlusions Wildfly was forcing its own Jackson lib located in `/wildfly/modules/system/layers/base/ path (e.g. wildfly/modules/system/layers/base/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core)` which is 2.10.5 for **Wildfly 21.0.2.** Wildfy is doing this regardless of specifing custom version in maven pom.xml. Also I wasn't able to find any mention about this "embedded" Jackson version in **Wildfly** through management console, so it was a bit pain to realize where is the problem. Maybe this will save someone else some time.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.3">
    <deployment>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-core" />
            <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-databind" />
            <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jackson-datatype-jdk8" />
            <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jackson-datatype-jsr310" />
            <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.jackson-jaxrs-json-provider" />
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson2-provider" />
        </exclusions>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="jdk.unsupported"/>
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```